# Random Forests as a Generalized Additive Model

Tags: python, regression, random-forest, non-linear-regression, gam

This is a regression problem. I have a dataset of sales of various products overtime. I have three kind of feature sets : `Price features, Product features and Seasonality`.

I want to build a customer estimator which is defined as follows : `y = a*price_features + RandomForest(Product features + Seasonality features)`.

Moreover if there would be a possibility to switch `RandomForest` with some other non linear estimator it would be even better.

So the model is linear for price features and non linear for product and seasonality features. How can i do something like this in python ? I am interpreting this problem as `GAMs` because I express the model as a sum of Linear and Nonlinear components. I know that `GAMs` are fitted using `backfitting` but i dont know if I should take the pain of writing the whole `backfitting` algorithm. Also i am pretty sure there isnt a package which provides the functionality to use `RandomForest` as a `GAM`. I would really appreciate some insights. Thanks

Comment: This might be a better question for [datascience.se] as you haven't provided a [mcve] and appear to be asking for general how-to or theory questions rather than specific coding answers

Comment: @G.Anderson yes i posted there too but the engagement of users is low, hence no replies yet.

Comment: You will need to explain `what y = a*price_features + RandomForest(Product features + Seasonality features)` means. This does not sound like a sensible form of modelling

Comment: @RobertWilson if you just think of the problem as `y~ f1(x1) + f2(x2) + noise` where `f2`is some nonlinear function of feature `x2`and `f1` is linear function of feature `x1`. Just like GAMs but here i would want to plug in a random forest as `f2`.

Comment: @SiddhantTandon This doesn't really clarify things. What is this random forest? What is it predicting?